# PHP script to read text file and Highlight phrase in it

Tags: php, text, colors, formatting, html

I'm total noob if it comes to PHP so thanks in advance for the understanding.

My target is to export particular strings from a text file to a webpage and highlight the searched phrase in color (bold red if the phrase is FAIL and bold green if the phrase is SUCCESS).

The file:

SERVER: arch-linux SCHEDULED_TASK: SendFilesToValidate SUCCEEDED (0)

Some code that prints out the file:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("FINE.TXT","r");

while(! feof($file))
{
    $file .= fgets($file). "<br />";
    $body_text= $file ;
    $searh_letter = 'FAILED'; 
    echo fgets($file). "<br />";
    echo '';
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to export the result of scheduled task to a text file and then to webpage. What should I fix in order to get this working as expected?

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the first occurrence of FAIL or SUCCESS.

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents("FINE.TXT");
if (($pos = strpos("FAIL", $fileContent)) !== false) {
    echo "<p class='fail'>".substr($fileContent, $pos, 4)."</p>";
} elseif (($pos = strpos("SUCCESS", $fileContent)) !== false) {
    echo "<p class='success'>".substr($fileContent, $pos, 7)."</p>";
} else {
    echo "phrase not found";
}
```

If FAIL or SUCCESS can occur in each line of your txt-file, use:

```
$file = file("FINE.TXT");
foreach ($file as $line) {
    if (($pos = strpos("FAIL", $line)) !== false) {
        echo "<p class='fail'>".substr($line, $pos, 4)."</p>";
    } elseif (($pos = strpos("SUCCESS", $line)) !== false) {
        echo "<p class='success'>".substr($line, $pos, 7)."</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Update: I get no output from all the answered suggestions, what can be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very easy way to do this.
But please notice PHP is case-sensitive:

> "Success" != "SUCCESS"

```
$content = file_get_contents("FINE.TXT");
$content = str_replace("Success", '<span style="font-weigt: bold; color: green; ">Success</span>', $content);
$content = str_replace("Failed", '<span style="font-weigt: bold; color: red; ">Failed</span>', $content);
echo $content;
```

Comment: Update: I get no output from all the answered suggestions, what can be wrong ?

Comment: Update: this one works, I cannot get the output to be printer line by line order...

Answer (score 0):

Best solutin IMHO:

```
<?php
```

$content = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$content = str_replace("Succeded", 'SUCCEEDED (0)', $content);
$content = str_replace("Failed", 'FAILED - PLEASE INVESTIGATE', $content);
$content = str_replace("SERVER:", 'SERVER > ', $content);
$content = str_replace("TASK:", 'TASK_NAME = ', $content);
$content = str_replace("SERVERNAMED@AD", 'SERVERNAMED@AD \  ', $content);
$content = str_replace("SERVERNAMED@AD", 'SERVERNAMED@AD \  ', $content);
**echo nl2br($content);** << this has done it line by line...

?>